# Real numbers that are not the roots of any polynomial equation with algebraic coefficients

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

An algebraic number is a number which is a root of some non-zero polynomial equation with rational coefficients.

A transcendental number is a number which is not a root of any non-zero polynomial equation with rational coefficients.

Are there any real numbers that are not the roots of any polynomial equation with algebraic coefficients?

I'm guessing that somebody must have asked this before somewhere, though I have not been able to find it, so please excuse me for the possible duplicate...

Thanks

Comment: Any trancendental number $p$ is the root of the polynomial $x - p$, which is a polynomial with irrational coefficients.

Comment: @Arthur: Thank you for pointing that out. I "tuned up" the question accordingly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complement of the transcendentals in $\mathbb{R}$ is the real [algebraic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number).  The algebraic numbers are [algebraically closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field).  Therefore every polynomial with non-transcendental coefficients has algebraic coefficients and thus algebraic roots.

Comment: So what you're saying is - we will not "get" transcendental roots **even** if we use irrational algebric coefficients?

Comment: Correct.  Make a polynomial with algebraic coefficients, get algebraic roots.  Since "algebraic" = "not transcendental", you can't get to the transcendentals using only the algebraics (in polynomials).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.

Comment: A nitpick: complement of transcendentals in $\Bbb R$ are _real_ algebraic numbers which aren't algebraically closed, since $x^2+1$ has no roots, algebraic or not.

Comment: @Wojowu : Right you are.  Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

"Are there real numbers ..." Yes, there are, and in fact those numbers coincide with the transcendental numbers. In fact, if $x$ is a root of a polynomial with non-transcendental(=algebraic) coefficients, then $x$ is itself algebraic.

Comment: So **no** transcendental number is a root of some polynomial equation with algebric coefficients?

Comment: @barakmanos exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've added non-trancendental (i.e. "algebraic") to the question, the answer is yes.

The roots of a polynomial with algebraic coefficients are also roots of some polynomial (possibly of higher degree) with rational coefficients.

Comment: That's an interesting notion (about the roots of a polynomial with algebraic coefficients being the roots of some polynomial with rational coefficients). Thanks.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think that the answer is in fact - yes. Even according to your own description (if I understand it correctly), not only there are real numbers that are not the roots of any polynomial equation with algebric coefficients, but there are many of them - all the transcendental numbers (an uncountable set).

Comment: The answer is yes, you're right. I just had the wrong question in mind when I wrote the answer.